# How to reattach a cast iron drainpipe

Tags: drainage, masonry, old-house

The cast iron drain pipe fell off my wall this morning. It’s the entire length from guttering to drain. It looks like it was attached with very old nails which have worked their way out, taking some of the mortar with them. So my plan is to fill the holes with mortar, wait for that to dry, then drill in and put anchor bolts in to reattach the pipe. Does that seem ok?

Edited to add, the wall is rubble stone. Also I’m not sure yet what size of anchor bolt. Probably quite big as the thing is heavy!

Thank you!

Comment: Cast iron is heavy, so why not replace it with plastic or aluminum down pipe?  Be easier to work with and will not need as robust an anchoring system.  This is for roof gutters, not a drain pipe for inside house?

Comment: A few pictures of the situation - where it detached from the top, one or more of the anchors that pulled out, where it ends at the bottom, and a nice overall shot - will help people better understand the situation and help them come up with good solutions for you.

Comment: Well it’s an old house so it feels like it would be a shame to lose the pipe. However, that is most definitely an option if I can’t reattach the thing! Yes it’s the down pipe from the guttering outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally there would be a hole in the stone/brick/mortar and then a wooden plug wedged into the hole and the rough nail goes into the wood. Over time the wood rots away and the nails become loose.

In the interest of authenticity (oh, and cheapness!) I would replace it in the traditional manner. Trim a piece of wood to relatively loosely fit the existing holes, being careful not to add much pressure, the nail will expand the wood a little and wedge it tight.

Then drill a pilot hole in the wood, slightly less than the nail diameter and gently tap the nails home. If the holes have become enlarged over time, you might need to add a little mortar and push the wooden plug into the mortar till it's flush. Once the mortar has set after a week or so (assuming it's lime mortar), you can drill your hole and tap in the nails.

Some folks use a pair of pieces of wood and the nail just goes in between them acting like a wedge.

Be very careful not to hit the cast iron obviously, it's as brittle as brittle can be. I use a hard plastic mallet.

Comment: That’s exactly what was in the hole, rotten wood.  And, I think what prevented the pipe from shattering when it fell off the wall was it landing on a patio chair and a tree that provided some cushioning! Your answer is perfect, thank you, I will give it a go!